# Magento2 - Is it possible to run jasmine tests without having a magento installation configured?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run jasmine tests without having a magento site configured?

As in purely from the project as it is on github (so without database)?

The furthest I’ve got is

> setup:di:compile

but than

> setup:static-content:deploy -f

fails because `The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default website can be configured in the `config.php` file. The documentation can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/test/js/jasmine.html).